# How to get List of Spool files from OUTQ to Java

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, jt400

1st i want to say thank you for viewing this Question :)

I'm a beginner to AS400/JAVA development. I want to know how to get spool file list to java and how to convert it to PDF from OUTQ, Using JT400.

Can anyone to tell me or give me sample java code ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll have better luck searching the web for the current platform name: IBM i, or even iSeries.  IBM have not made an 'AS400' for over 10 years.

Comment: @BuckCalabro IBM marketing is not easy to understand for mortal men. Rebranding several times within a decade would have been bad for most other companies. Also most classes in jt400 refers to AS400 every where.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Rebranding is a big pain for all of us - you are so right.  Heck, even the Infocenter link has 'iseries' in the URL.  But when I search for current information under 'as400' I get a lot of old results.  In the Java world especially, old advice is bad advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split it in two.

One is reading the characters in the spool file.  I did this a few years back.  I believe there is a SPoolFile class where you then need to search for the actual spool file given the job name/user name/job number triplet and then choose the one of potentially many generated by that job.  Then you need to transform it (I had to use cp850 on our host as the code page) but the rest eludes me.

The second is to generate a PDF file containing the characters read. This is a pure Java thing - I believe it was iText I used and it was pretty straight forward.

Comment: The IBM Javadoc for [SpooledFileList](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzahh%2Fjavadoc%2Fcom%2Fibm%2Fas400%2Faccess%2FSpooledFileList.html) is in the IBM i Information Center.  They have a [class finder search tool](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzas6/rzas6finder.htm), too.

Answer (score 0):

```
            SpooledFile spooledFile = new SpooledFile(as400, splfName.trim(), Integer.parseInt(spoolFileNumber), jobName.trim(), jobUser.trim(), jobNumber.trim());
            PrintParameterList printParms = new PrintParameterList();
            printParms.setParameter(PrintObject.ATTR_WORKSTATION_CUST_OBJECT, "/QSYS.LIB/QWPDEFAULT.WSCST");
            printParms.setParameter(PrintObject.ATTR_MFGTYPE, "*WSCST");
            try {
                InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(spooledFile.getTransformedInputStream(printParms), "cp850");
                char[] buf = new char[32767];
                outputData = new StringBuilder();
                if (in.ready()) {
                    int bytesRead = 0;
                    bytesRead = in.read(buf, 0, buf.length);
                    while (bytesRead > 0) {
                        outputData.append(buf, 0, bytesRead);
                        bytesRead = in.read(buf, 0, buf.length);
                    }
                }
            //    System.out.println(sbuf.toString());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```